# Why does Shake not provide a MonadMask instance for Action?

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I would like to use the [`temporary` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/temporary) with [Shake](http://shakebuild.com/), but that requires `Action` to have an instance for `MonadMask`, which is missing. Why does Shake not provide such an instance?

Comment: https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/186

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two reasons:

- It's impossible, since `Action` is based on a continuation monad, and you can't implement `MonadMask` for a continuation monad. See [this blog post](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/continuations-and-exceptions.html) for a rough justification of why that is impossible.
- It's undesirable, since then you could make choices depending on whether a dependent rule succeeds or fails, whereas in Shake the failure of a rule you depend on should always result in you failing.

However, Shake does provide `actionFinally` and `actionOnException` as building blocks, which are a restricted variant of the functions available in `MonadMask`. In addition, Shake provides `withTempFile` and `withTempDir`, which do some of the same things as the `temporary` package. And finally, if you are entirely in `IO`, then `liftIO` and `bracket` works fine.